# What is the best way to create surface for 2D vertical scroll shooter?

Tags: android, android-canvas, surfaceview, game-engine

I develop the first game (2D vertical scroll shooter) for android. I think about how to make the gaming surface. There are two options.

- Firstly, the aircraft can fly within a single window, and animation
  will come from changing backgrounds.
- Secondly, I probably can make a
  long canvas. The aircraft will be flying all over the gaming surface,
  and the animation will happen naturally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have a look at [AndEngine](http://www.andengine.org/).

It's a free open source java engine for Android.

- [Demo App](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.anddev.andengine.examples), check *Backgrounds* > *Using an AutoParallaxBackground*. The source code of those examples is also free.
- [Good tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/12065/how-to-create-a-simple-android-game), to start.
- [GameEngine Sources and its Extensions](https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEngine).

Comment: thank you. I've already started to study this engine, so I understood that I would hard without him.